# Introducir una fecha mediante input()

Tags: python, python-3.x

¡Hola a todos!
Necesito su ayuda con un pequeño problema que me ha estado comiendo la cabeza.
En mi programa creé una función que trabaja por medio de fechas, pero en algún punto de esta, necesita una entrada con input. El problema es que necesito que sea de tipo fecha (datetime.date) y lleve el formato (YYYY, MM, DD).
¿Alguna sugerencia?

Por ejemplo, probé con volver cambiar el input a int, pero mostraba el error...

```
dia1 = int(input('Por favor introduce una fecha:'))

OUTPUT: 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2020, 4, 22'
```

¡Gracias!

PD: No puedo descomponer la fecha en varios elementos puesto que después necesito operar con ella como un solo elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor manera de hacerlo es colocando varios `input` y al final hacer un `print` de la forma en que quieres que se muestren los valores.

El `input()` método solo puede tomar texto del terminal. Tendrás que encontrar una manera de analizar ese texto y convertirlo en una fecha.

Podrías hacerlo de dos maneras diferentes:

Primero, debes importar la librería(en tu código):

`import datetime
from datetime import timedelta`

Luego, solicita al usuario que ingrese las 3 partes de una fecha por separado, así que llame `input()` tres veces, convierta los resultados en enteros y cree una fecha:

`año = int(input('Introduzca un año'))
mes = int(input('Introduzca un mes'))
dia = int(input('Introduzca un día'))
fecha = datetime.date(año, mes, dia)`

Si no, solicita al usuario que ingrese la fecha en un formato específico , luego convierta ese formato en los tres números de año, mes y día:

`datos = input('Introduzca una fecha de forma YYYY-MM-DD')
año, mes, dia = map(int, datos.split('-'))
fecha = datetime.date(año, mes, dia)`

Comment: No puedo hacer esto puesto que necesito que se tome como un solo elemento, por que después opero con la fecha

Comment: Por favor el código como texto, no hay necesidad de imágenes además de que son poco legibles

Comment: De acuerdo, edité la publicación. Podrías observarla e intentar probar. Ambos puntos que coloqué son sólo ejemplos, no incluí nada sobre manejo de excepciones ni manejo de errores.

Comment: Exacto, pero cada valor lo puedes introducir en una fecha como te mostré anteriormente. Puedes intentarlo, luego opera con esa fecha la mayoría de veces que amerites.

Comment: Perdón, creo que me expliqué mal. Deseo que mi programa sea intuitivo, y que calcule con dos preguntas varios datos sobre la persona. Sin embargo, sería tedioso explicar una por una... ¿alguna idea?

Comment: @Krypt0NGeek pero el resultado final de este código ES un solo elemento (fecha) y en el segundo ejemplo también manejas un solo elemento de string (datos) que temporalmente se divide en tres y que podría servir para realizar un chequeo de la validez de los datos. Incluso puedes omitir el split si usas strptime().

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar una clase que te cree un objeto de tipo fecha, es decir, ingresas por separado los datos de dia, mes y año y lo almacenas como un objeto con formato, ejemplo:

la clase seria algo como:

```
class FechaHora:
__dia=0
__mes=0
__año=0
__hora=0
__minutos=0
__segundos=0

def __init__ (self, dia=1, mes=1,year=2020):
    if((mes>0 and mes<=12)):       #Este sector valida los datos ingresados
        if((year%400==0)or(year%100!=0 and year%4==0)):      #Este sector valida si es año bisiesto
            listames=[31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
        else:
            listames=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
        if(dia<=listames[mes-1] and dia > 0):
            self.__dia = dia
            self.__mes = mes
            self.__año = year
        else:
            print("El dia esta fuera de rango")
    else:
        print("Hubo un error, verifique los datos ingresados")
    def Mostrar(self):
        print('Fecha: {}/{}/{}'.format(self.__dia, self.__mes, self.__año))
```

dentro de esto trabajas los metodos necesarios para obtener si lo deseas de forma separada la fecha.
el programa principal podria ser algo como esto:

```
from ClaseFechaHora import FechaHora

if __name__=='__main__':

       print("**** Hora y Fecha1 ****")
       dia=int(input("Dia: "))
       mes=int(input("Mes: "))
       año=int(input("Año: "))

       r=FechaHora(dia,mes,año)

       r.Mostrar()
```

El resultado de la consola te quedaria algo asi por ejemplo:

```
**** Hora y Fecha1 **** 
Dia: 8 
Mes: 5 
Año: 2020 
Fecha: 8/5/2020
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>
repetir = True  # Variable para controlar el bucle
while repetir == True:  # Comprobamos que la variable se correcta.
    fecha = input("Introduce fecha en formato YYYY,MM,DD ->  ")# Solicitamos fecha
    patron = re.compile(r'^\d{1,},\d{1,},\d{1,}$')# puedes cambiar el patron
    encontrado = patron.search(fecha)
    if encontrado:# si el patron exite intentamos guardarla en datetime.time
        try:# Si la fecha no exite da una excepción 
            fechadate = datetime.date( # guardamos la fecha usando split para dividir el str
                int(fecha.split(",")[0]), 
                int(fecha.split(",")[1]), 
                int(fecha.split(",")[2]))
            repetir = False #todo correcto terminamos el bucle.
        except:
            print("Fecha no valida.")
print(fechadate)
</code>
```